# I am getting TypeError : Postitional argument

Tags: python

```py
class learn:
    def __init__(self, first_name: str, last_name: str, age: int):
        self.first_name = first_name
        self.last_name = last_name
        self.age = age

    def __str__(self, acc):
        if isinstance(acc, learn):
            return f' My name is {self.first_name} {self.last_name} and I am {self.age}'
        raise Exception(f"{acc} is not of class learn ")


acc = learn('Ranjeet', 'Kumar', 22)
print(acc)
```

`TypeError: __str__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'acc'`

Comment: In your own words, where you have `def __str__(self, acc):`, what do you think the `self` part means? What do you think it will refer to? Where do you expect the value for `acc` to come from? Also, did you try to [research](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) the problem? For example, you could try putting `how do I write a __str__ method in python` [into a search engine](https://duckduckgo.com/?t=q=how+do+I+write+a+__str__method+in+python). It really is that easy to look things up.

Answer (score 1):

As described in the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html?highlight=__str__#object.__str__), your custom `__str__()` method should only declare a single parameter, `self` that will always be of the type of your class, i.e. `learn`:

```py
def __str__(self):
    return f' My name is {self.first_name} {self.last_name} and I am {self.age}'

# call via built-in functions str(acc) or print(acc)
```

Contrast this with a separate function that is detached from the class and could take any number of arguments:

```py
def to_string(obj):
    if isinstance(obj, learn):
        return f' My name is {obj.first_name} {obj.last_name} and I am {obj.age}'
    raise Exception(f"{obj} is not of class learn ")

# call via to_string(acc)
```